# Drools -Dyanmic Date comparison with manipulation of current date

Tags: java, drools

I have a java class which has person creation date field.

```
public class PersonPer 


public Date getCreationDate() {
    return creationDate == null ? null : new 
Date(creationDate.getTime());
}

public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
    this.creationDate = creationDate == null ? null : new 
    Date(creationDate.getTime());
}
```

I need to compare this creationdate should be less than , reducing X months from Current Date(I want to pass X months value, say 3 months, from configuration file/java file) in Drools. i.e. Current date - 10th June,2018, X month(3month) - 10th April, 2018, the creation date should be before 10th April, 2018.

But it is not working.

1) How do I pass dyanmic value(from java) to 'function in drools'?

JAVA(Junit for now) ->

```
    `int RepresentativeAppointmentMonth=3
    session.insert(personPer);
    session.insert(RepresentativeAppointmentMonth);`
```

DRL -->

```
 declare Facts
 ...
 repMonth:RepMonth

 ..
 end
 declare RepMonth
     month: int
 end

 function Date workWithDates(int m)
 {

 ..

 return NewDateWithMmonthsubtractedFromCurrentDate;
 }

rule "Date check"
when
    RepMonth(m : month)`    //<- But if I add this line, the next line doesn't trigger, if I comment this line, it works, with static value of Months(hardcoding 3 months-> which I dont want.
    PersonPer(CreationDate > workWithDates(m))
then 
    System.out.println("Rep");
end
```

2) Any other suggestion to handle this? I have tried a lot of ways but there is something missing. I am new to Drools.

Comment: You are never inserting a `RepMonth` object into your session. That's why adding that pattern is preventing the rule to being activated.

Comment: @EstebanAliverti Thank you. It worked. 
I had a follow-up question. Currently, I was working with Junit to fire the rules, and the drool files were in src/test/... path and it was getting triggered. Is there a way to identify where the drl file rules get triggered from actual java src file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Esteban said that you have to add RepMonth object in into your session. Do this in your java code

```
    int RepresentativeAppointmentMonth=3
    RepMonth repMonth = new RepMonth(RepresentativeAppointmentMonth);
    session.insert(personPer);
    session.insert(repMonth);
    session.insert(RepresentativeAppointmentMonth);
```

Comment: Thank you. I added the repMonth to the session and it worked!